# ogrinfo filter invalid geometries

Tags: gdal, ogrinfo

I have shapefile and I want to filter all invalid geometries.

```
ogrinfo -q /workspace/INVALID/0.shp -sql "SELECT * FROM \"0\"" -fid 1749

Layer name: 0
OGRFeature(0):1749
  Target (Real) = 175.00
  Actual (Real) = 190.00
  Timestamp (String) = 7/5/2016 10:52:28 AM
  POLYGON ((nan nan,nan nan,nan nan,nan nan,nan nan))
```

So I'd like to filter it with sql somehow. Is it possible without function like `MakeValid` or similar?

Comment: It is possible to use IsValid and MakeValid with ogrinfo, why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @user30184, hi. Because I guess I can't use it in my environment `ERROR 1: Undefined function 'ST_MakeValid' used`

Comment: Okay, I got this work with `OGR_GEOM_AREA`, I just check if it is positive

Comment: You can also use `-dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT * FROM \"0\" where ST_IsValid(geometry)=1"`.

Comment: @user30184, thanks for info. Because I noticed that sometimes I have POINT as geometry and my workaround does not work. So your solution is the best for now